# In how many ways can 5 identical rings be worn in 4 fingers of a hand.

Tags: permutations, combinations

The problem i am getting is that Well let me put this clearly , 5 identical rings meaning that if 5 of them are work in one finger and if their place is changed it doesn't matter its still counted as one. now keeping that in mind I can't use the permutation formula nPr...so what i am suppose to do? the book says the answer is 1024 i don't know how.

Comment: You are looking for the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of 5 into 4 parts.  You want four ordered numbers, which can be zero, that add to 5. The answer comes out of a [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach.  Read those and you may be able to solve it yourself.  I get a much smaller number than 1024

Comment: Do you want to find how much sums $5=n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$ exist where the $n_i$ are nonnegative integers? If so then seek your hail in [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: The answer $1024 = 4^5$, but that suggests that the rings are distinguishable and that the order in which they are placed on a finger does not matter (in which case the count is four choices of finger for each of the five rings).

Comment: N.F taussing well thats what i thought 4^5 but if you think about it clearly then what your saying is that Each finger has 5 ways of wearing which meaning any number of them can be worn at a time this means that 5 ways in the first 5 in the second 5 in third and so on meaning 5x5x5x5=5^4 not 4^5.

Comment: @BilalKing  We are selecting the fingers on which to place each ring, not the other way around.  However, if the rings are identical, the answer is $\binom{5 + 3}{3}$.

Comment: Ummm...I don't get what you said but i am pretty sure its Right so either you can tell me what you mean or direct me to some webpage.....thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you phrased your question is misleading.  For the answer to make sense, the rings cannot be identical.  On the other hand, the order in which the rings are placed on the fingers does not matter (which is what you seem to be saying when you say it does not matter if the places of the rings on one of the fingers is interchanged).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thats exactly what i am trying to say..the order does not matter since they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of partitioning a string of 5 elements (stars) into 4 parts, which can be done by adding 3 bars into the string. Then you pick the places for the 3 bars (there are 5+3 total slots in the string) and you know the resulting configuration. So you have $\binom{5+3}{3}$ ways to do that...

Comment: Aren't there only three bars?  It takes three cuts to make four pieces.

Comment: @RossMillikan you are right, fixed

Comment: You missed one place that it says 4 bars

Comment: well umm I don't understand the bar and string technique but the solution your providing i think its wrong .Why? well for starters i know that the answer will be in hundreds not just a two digit number its obvious from the number of rings and fingers as i said the book says 1024 which i don't understand.

Comment: @RossMillikan fixed again, thanks

Comment: @BilalKing as long as the rings are identical, it's the correct answer. If each ring is different, it would be a different story

Comment: You meant to say there are $5 + \color{red}{3}$ total slots in the string.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes fixed

Comment: You correctly answered the question that was asked, hence my upvote.  However, I suspect, based on the answer, that the actual question was how many ways can five (distinguishable) rings be placed on four fingers if the order in which the rings are placed on a particular finger does not matter.

Comment: I just read about the bar and star method and it din't help me figuring out how you got to your answer ....:/ I mean really if I can do Quantam physics  i should be able to do this if you just explain a little ...pretty please

Comment: If you don't have the time to explain then just tell me that your a 100% certain that the answer is 56

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve these kinds of problems, you have to visualize which of the given things is a base. Let me explain. 
The fingers are fixed in this case. Hence, it is the base. Now keeping in mind this picture of fixed fingers, think of the first ring. The first ring can be put in any of the 4 fingers. Similarly the next and the next and so on. 
This 4 × 4 × 4 × 4 ×4 =4^5 = 1024
This method can be iced in letterbox, letter problem too. The base there, would be the fixed letter box.

Comment: But the rings are identical, what you're suggesting applies to when the rings are not identical.